# Karate: Is there any way to know if Karate finishes test run of the test suite?

Tags: karate

I need to perform some task after my test run, of the test suite, is completed by Karate. So, is there any way, I can understand that the test run is completed? I can do that for test package individually, but need to know if karate completes the test run. At the point when karate publishes its own test run status. For example: sending mail after whole test suite is done.

It would be a great help if anyone can help me.

Thank you